g++ -g debug symbols don't include filename
I've been trying to get lldb working recently and I ran across the issue of breakpoints not being able to find files. So I did a small test, wrote an empty main function and compiled it with MinGW g++ -g -O0.
Accesing it then in lldb using image lookup -vn main to look at the function and I see this:
CompileUnit: id = {0x00000000}, file = "", language = "c++14"
       Function: id = {0x00000077}, name = "main", range = [0x00000001400017d0-0x00000001400017e8)
       FuncType: id = {0x00000077}, byte-size = 0, line = 3:5, compiler_type = "int (void)"
         Blocks: id = {0x00000077}, range = [0x1400017d0-0x1400017e8)
      LineEntry: [0x00000001400017d0-0x00000001400017d8): :4:1
         Symbol: id = {0xffffffff}, range = [0x00000001400017d0-0x00000001400017f0), name="main"

It would seem like when g++ adds the symbols it doesn't include the file name or path for some reason.
Not sure what is left to do if my g++ for some reason is broken. Here is the version for anyone interested:
g++ (MinGW-W64 x86_64-msvcrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.0.1 20230122 (experimental)

My guess would be that your version of lldb isn't fully compatible with mingw gcc. Have you tried doing the same lookup in gdb?

I'm guessing that by now -g for gcc means use the new-ish DWARF5 standard.
The lldb-1500 series had some preliminary support for DWARF5 - but not the line table changes.  One symptom of using these older lldb's on DWARF5 binaries was missing file names just like you showed, so I suspect this is what is going on.  You can test this either by passing -gdwarf4 to your gcc compile line.  Alternately, you could try a 1600 era lldb, which does support the DWARF5 line tables.

-gdwarf-4 seems to have done the trick thanks
